# Add Images to video

Tags: video, photo-editing

I want to add some images to my mp4 video,one at the beginning and 3-4 at the end, thats all, I dont have any experience with videos before, whats the best software for do that? Im using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Did you read my question? Im not asking for video software edition, my question is specific for add an image to video, its not a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend Openshot, a multi-purpose simple video-editor. Of course, it does have image overlays like most video editors such as kdenlive.
You can install it by simply opening the editor with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. And typing the following command: `Sudo apt install openshot`

Comment: Ok, so image overlays is the tech term for what I want to do?

Comment: Yes, it is.  You can remember it by "**lay**ing the **image  over** the video"

Comment: I was expecting maybe some ffmpeg command for do what I want, your answer guide me for make a better search..

Comment: I never heard of using sotware for ffmpeg commands. I thought that was doable from a command line. Could you explain what you're going for?

Comment: Needless to say, I know that many video editors use ffmpeg but I thought it was in a graphical interface. If you want to use ffmpeg commands, you can always install [the actual ffmpeg framework](https://www.ffmpeg.org/)

Comment: Here's [how to do it](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12105/add-an-image-overlay-in-front-of-video-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: I just used this command: ffmpeg -i "concat:input.mp4|picture.mp4" -c copy output.mp4 but its not wortking...

Comment: Read [this answer!](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/12111)

Comment: Yes I found it but it did not work... I'll check the software you recommended thanks!